# Error calling Google Cloud function - limits exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

I am calling a GCP cloud function from salesforce, integration working fine, now I am getting the following error. It seems I have to increase the quota, but my billing account do not allow me to open a support case. It will cost me $29 for basic support.

Is there anyway I can increase the quote for my cloud function allocation myself ?

> You have temporarily exceeded a Cloud Shell limit. To increase or
> reset your quota, please file a support case

Any pointer is appreciated. I am stuck at this point.

Thank you,

Comment: Cloud Shell is simply a cloud-based environment for running `gcloud` and related commands/actions, and it's not clear what action you're trying to take that's hitting a Cloud *Shell* limit. You may want to try installing the cloud tools to your local machine and then attempting the same deployment to Cloud Functions; if you have further details please [edit] your post.

Comment: The weekly usage quota is 50 hours per week. To change the quota, you must have paid support and billing enabled for your project. I recommend that you install the Google Cloud tools on a local system so that you are not consuming the Cloud Shell quota. You can read more at these links: https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quotas-limits and https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install

Comment: I am now using google cloud cli in my local and testing my function locally which is working fine. I will be careful going forward. Is there a report I can see in my google cloud console to view my usage allocation total and consumed thus far. cc @nanofarad and John Hanley

Comment: Details in my first link. **Click Session information and then click Usage quota. A dialog appears and displays the hours remaining in your quota, the total number of hours in your quota, and the date and time that the quota resets.**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @John Hanley mentioned, To change the quota, you must have paid support and billing enabled for your project. You install the Google Cloud tools on a local system so that you are not consuming the Cloud Shell quota. You can read more at these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quotas-limits) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install)

You can request a higher quota limit as follows from the console:

- Go to the Quotas page: [Page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?walkthrough_id=cloud_quota_request)
- Go to Quotas
  On the Quotas page, find the quota you want to increase in the Quota column.
- Select the checkbox to the left of your quota.
- Click create EDIT QUOTAS. The Quota changes form displays.
- In the Quota changes form, enter the increased quota that you want for your project in the New limit field.
- Complete any additional fields in the form, and then click DONE.
- Click SUBMIT REQUEST.

All these steps are listed in the [documentations](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota)

Viewing the quota increase request status: [click_here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#viewing_quot_increase_requests)

Maximum quota to be approved is 50 hours per week with Contacting Support and providing project-number, etc.